# C# - Overriding an outputdatareceived event handler

Tags: c#, events, process, overriding

My question is extremely similar to [C# - Overriding an Event Handler - Adding a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994599/c-sharp-overriding-an-event-handler-adding-a-parameter/3994655#3994655)

I tried what Jon Skeet suggested but whenever my process raises the event, I get an exception that there is no object associated with the process. How is that possible if a process raised the event?

I'm working on a program that reads a list of machines from a text file and then for each computer it creates a process which starts cmd.exe and runs a dir command to search the target machine for a certain file. Here's a bit of my code. Please excuse the messiness, I usually write something, run into problems and then try a bunch of things before cleaning it up. I'm still pretty new at this.

```
foreach (var machine in machines)
{
    using (Process searcher = new Process())
    {
        searcher.StartInfo = cmd;
        searcher.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C dir \\\\" + machine + "\\c$\\*.pst /a/s";
        searcher.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(searcher_ErrorDataReceived);
        searcher.Start();

        searcher.BeginOutputReadLine();
        searcher.BeginErrorReadLine();

        if (!searcher.HasExited)
        {
            searcher.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => HandleData(procCount, args);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(searcher.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

My `HandleData` method looks like this:

```
private void HandleData(int ID, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    if (this.outputBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(HandleData);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { ID, args });
    }
    else
    {
        this.outputBox.AppendText(args.Data);
        processes[ID] += args.Data + "\n";
    }
}
```

`outputBox` is a Windows Forms object that I write to, and it works, but not for the processes which run the commands on computers that are offline. The exception occurs on the line

```
this.outputBox.AppendText(args.Data);
```

and is a `NullReferenceException`. `args.Data` is null. So it seems that even though dir usually outputs "machine offline" or something similar to the command prompt, it doesn't write that to its output stream and I'm at a loss as to how to get around this.

My main question is: how do I keep the outputs of each process together without losing the asynchronous reading that I have now? Each process needs to start, do it's thing and then every line that it writes to its own output stream needs to be kept together so I can read it all back in its entirety.

Comment: If "machine offline" is an error, I'd expect it to be written to stderr - does this message arrive via `ErrorDataReceived` instead?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie I've got an ErrorDataReceived event handler that shows a message box with the error but the DataReceivedEventArgs that is passed to the handler is empty which is why I thought maybe it was writing it to it's output stream. It's possible I've misunderstood how ErrorDataReceived works though.

Comment: It seems to me that the behaviour is correct - you get an error, which goes to stderr. There's no output to stdout due to the error, so `args.Data` is null.

Comment: I don't understand why it's calling HandleData then, because that's only supposed to be called when the output stream is written to. Or does the OutputDataReceived event get raised regardless of whether the output is sent to stdout or stderr?

Comment: I guess closing the stream is still considered to be a write operation. Note that the [msdn sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) also checks whether `Data` is null, so it's clearly expected behaviour

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing me to the sample code. Luckily that was an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

After a fair bit of experimenting, I rewrote my code. I created a class that takes in a computer name but also keeps track of the output, error and handles the process that will be running CMD. In my forms object, I used a thread per searcher object so that each searcher could search and wait for its associated process to exit before disposing of it without holding up the rest of the program.

My main problem was finding a pattern to use in this case. It's sort of the opposite of the observer class because I have a number of subjects (the searchers) and only one listener (the form). I ended up just creating a ProgressEventArgs class and raising events when the process associated with each searcher started or stopped. I created a custom Exited event for when the process associated with each searcher exited (which the form subscribed to) so that the form could count how many searchers had finished and read all of their outputs if all of them had finished.

I shudder to think of all the redundancies I may have introduced or the existing methods I could have used but you can't use what you don't know. Thanks Simon for the help!